# Variables not getting referenced while calling the shell script in the azure pipelines

Tags: azure, shell, azure-devops

This is my first time working with azure pipelines, I started creating my azure-pipeline.yml. I am trying to execute the azure DevOps pipeline. However I am getting to errors where the variable are not referenced as declared.

```
deploy.sh deploy_azr ${{ variables.subPref }} ${{ variables.rgType }} ${{ variables.location }} ${{ variables.config }}
```

Here is the start of my template

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
   include:
     - 'bicep/*'
     - 'azure-pipelines.yml'
   exclude:
     - '*'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'test_branch') }}:
    deployTarget: tst
    subscription: testsubscription
    subscriptionId: 26455-trt31-******
    rgType: tstrg
    subPref: *****
    config: tstjson
    location: eastus2
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
    deployTarget: prd
    subscription: prdsub
    subscriptionId: ***********************
    rgType: prdrg
    subPref: ******
    config: prd.json
    location: eastus2

stages:
  - stage: Deploylib
    jobs:
      - deployment: lib
        environment: ${{ variables.subscription }}
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: self
                - task: AzureCLI@2
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: ${{ variables.subscription }}
                    scriptType: 'bash'
                    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
                    inlineScript: |
                      set -e
                      set -x
                      sudo apt install -y gridsite-clients
                      cd 'bicep'
                      echo "starting the lib deployment"
                      deploy.sh deploy_azr ${{ variables.subPref }} ${{ variables.rgType }} ${{ variables.location }} ${{ variables.config }}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need to specify the correct environment name on this line,

```
jobs:
  - deployment: lib
    environment: <environment name>
```

You can create an environment on the DevOps page, see the reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops), then copy the name to the YAML above.

The concept of `environment` here represents a collection of resources you will deploy your code. Once you have run a deployment, you should be able to see the history of deployment in the target environment.

Answer (score 0):

> /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 42, Col: 22): Unexpected value ''

Test the same YAML sample and reproduce the same issue.

[image]

The cause of the issue is that you are using the format: `${{ variables.subscription }}` in YAML sample.

The variable will be processed at compile time.

To solve this issue, you can change to use the format: `$(subscription)`

For example:

```
jobs:
  - deployment: lib
    environment: $(subscription)
```

**Result:**

[image]

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Runtime expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax)

Comment: Hi @Kevin, Thank for the response.
I am unable to pass the parameters to the deply,sh script using the variables I defined.

i am trying as below
deploy.sh  ${{ variables.subPref }} ${{ variables.rgType }} ${{ variables.location }} ${{ variables.config }}

Comment: Have you tried to pass the variable to sh file with the format `$(variablename)`?  When you pass variables to sh file what is the result of it ? Can you share the error page ?

Comment: In fact, I tried with $(variablename) as well, it didn't work either.

It is just passing the empty string instead of the reference variable value

/home/vsts/work/1/s/bicep/deploy.sh
Deploying anonlib ...
+ location=
+ subPref=
+ rgType=
+ config=

Comment: Can you update the question to share the current status of the issue?